# rails 6 and vue.js new project fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

Just following the tutorial below to integrate rails 6 with vue:

https://medium.com/@akshaych2786/vue-js-with-rails-6-and-performing-crud-operations-b043ef3691f2

But then rails fails to run. This is with no changes to the project, just following the tutorial. Some sort of dependency madness, but i'm new to vue and don't really understand what the issue is. And yes, i did run `yarn install --check-files`, same error. And yes, if i set `check_yarn_integrity` to `false`, then it works fine. But i'm not sure if i'm going to get into trouble by disabling this check.

```
$ rails g controller Welcome index
Warning: the running version of Bundler (2.1.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (2.1.4). We suggest you to upgrade to the version that created the lockfile by running `gem install bundler:2.1.4`.


========================================
  Your Yarn packages are out of date!
  Please run `yarn install --check-files` to update.
========================================


To disable this check, please change `check_yarn_integrity`
to `false` in your webpacker config file (config/webpacker.yml).


yarn check v1.22.4
success Folder in sync.
Done in 0.18s.
yarn check v1.22.4
error "vue-loader#@vue/component-compiler-utils#lru-cache#yallist" is wrong version: expected "^2.1.2", got "3.1.1"
error Found 1 errors.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/check for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: First off, I would fix that bundler error with `gem install bundler:2.1.4`

Comment: Then, can you try deleting the `node_modules` directory, running `yarn` again, and seeing if that fixes it?